# Is it possible to stop a Timer from a separate class?

Tags: java, swing, class, timer, timertask

I am trying to reset a Timer so as to avoid having multiple instances of it. To achieve this, I want to stop the Timer from a separate class, something like this:

```
public void Timer() 
{
    Timer timer = new Timer(); 
    long interval = (1000) ;
    timer.schedule( new TimerTask() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            // code //       
        }
    }, 0, interval);         
}

public void Stop() 
{
    // stop Timer //
}
```

I feel this may be achievable by terminating Timer(); if it is not possible to stop the Timer I would much appreciate being shown how I could best go about terminating the class as cleanly as possible. Thank you.

Comment: As you currently have it, you won't be able to do anything with the timer as it is local to `Timer`, a `void` returning method.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I'm sorry, when it comes to OOP I am hopeless. What could I change to make this work?

Comment: There are many options in that regard but all involve getting the timer out of the method. One way would be to have it as member on the class with `Timer()` and `Stop()`.

Comment: You used the Swing tag which means you should be using a Swing Timer, not an AWT Timer. See [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). ` I want to stop the Timer from a separate class` - the Timer is no different than any other Java object. If you want to reference the Timer in another class then the other class needs a reference to the Timer variable. How you do this is based on your current design. which we know nothing about so we can't give a specific suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I devised a pretty rudimentary solution:

```
boolean stop;
public void Timer() 
{
    Timer timer = new Timer(); 
    long interval = (1000) ;
    timer.schedule( new TimerTask() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            if condition is met{
                execute
            }
            else if(stop == true){
                timer.cancel();
            }       
        }
    }, 0, interval);         
}

.
.
.

stop = true;
try {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
stop = false;
Timer1();
```

Basically, the boolean value stops the Timer, gives it 2 seconds to make sure there is no overlap, and is then set back to false to safely reset the Timer.

Answer (score 1):

Newtimer.java

```
public class NewTimer{
   public Timer timer;
   public long interval;

public NewTimer(){
   if(instance == null){
      timer = new Timer(); 
      interval = (1000); 
   }
}
public void start() 
{
    timer.schedule( new TimerTask() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            // code //       
        }
    }, 0, interval);         
}

public void Stop() 
{
    // stop Timer //
}
```

On the other class, you can you this object class.

```
NewTimer newTimer = new NewTimer();

//Start timer
newTimer.start();

if(newTimer != null){
   //reinitialize
}
```

Check if there is an instance of the *timer* class. If it does, you can just reinitialize it.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I am unsure where you mean to place this line. Or rather, I don't see how I would go about initialising the Timer from within the Timer itself.

Comment: Thank you so much for this code; I understand all you have done here save for `if(instance == null)` . If you could please provide a short example of what sort of thing I should put here I would much appreciate it.

Comment: It all depends on how you use it. If you initialized it and started the timer on the same function, you don't have to do that. You can just use the start function again. On the other hand, if you have the NewTimer as a global variable, you will need to check if the newtimer has been initialized. Cause if you don't, you might get a null exception.